# CodeIgniter and AJAX form submit

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to save data submitted from a form into my mysql database and and then update the div element with the last posted item prepended to the list in the div.

Right now I am only trying to get a response back, I'm not worried about having the formatting correct at the moment.

My problem is the form won't submit with `e.preventDefault();` in place, but without it the form does the normal method of posting to the db then refreshing the page.

Here is my AJAX call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('form#feedInput').submit(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo site_url('dashboard/post_feed_item'); ?>",
            data: $('.feed-input').val(),
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data){
                debugger;
                $('#feed-container').prepend(data);
            },
            error: function() { alert("Error posting feed."); }
       });

    });
});
```

I don't think it's necessary for me to post my controller code, seeing as how my issue is the form won't make it past the `e.preventDefault();` function.

How can I get this form to submit via AJAX if the `e.preventDefault()` function is stopping it before it can reach the `$.ajax()` function?

Comment: console throwing an error?

Comment: It's not stopping it's prevent your site state, check your code in firebug console,, and what is this debugger;

Comment: there is nothing logged in the console

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `data` attribute of the ajax call is invalid. It should be either in JSON format `{ key: $('.feed-input').val() }` or in query format `'key='+$('.feed-input').val()`.
Also there is an unnecessary `debugger` variable in the success method.

A working code could be:

```
$('form#feedInput').submit(function(e) {

    var form = $(this);

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo site_url('dashboard/post_feed_item'); ?>",
        data: form.serialize(), // <--- THIS IS THE CHANGE
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data){
            $('#feed-container').prepend(data);
        },
        error: function() { alert("Error posting feed."); }
   });

});
```

Comment: Okay, so now it's submitted to the database but not updating the div with the response...

Comment: Check what is returned. `console.log(data)` or `alert(data)`

Comment: I get nothing returned. The alert window is blank. Does that mean the error is within my php?

Comment: Great. Thank you very much. I can take it from here. I'm just not very good with javascript.

Answer (score 4):

**Html part in view**

```
<form id="comment" method="post">
    <h2>Enter Your Details</h2>
    <center><div id="result"></div></center>

    <div class="form_fld">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Full Name" name="name" required=""> 
    </div>
    <div class="form_fld">
        <label>Email ID</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email ID" name="email" required="">
    </div>
    <div class="form_fld">
        <label>Contact Number</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Contact Number" name="contact" required="">
    </div>
    <div class="form_fld">
        <label>Developer</label>
        <select name="developer">
            <option>Lotus</option>
            <option>Ekta</option>
            <option>Proviso</option>
            <option>Dosti</option>
            <option>All</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form_fld">
        <button type="submit" id="send">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**After Html Part Just put ajax request**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/'); ?>js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#comment").submit(function(){
        dataString = $("#comment").serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "home/contact",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data){
                // alert('Successful!');
                $("#result").html('Successfully updated record!'); 
                $("#result").addClass("alert alert-success");
            }

        });

        return false;  //stop the actual form post !important!

    });
});
</script>
```

**Within Controller**

```
public function contact()
{
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $data = array('name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                  'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                  'number' => $this->input->post('contact'),
                  'developer' => $this->input->post('developer'),
                  'ip' => $ip,
                  'date' =>  date("d/m/Y"));
    $result = $this->User_model->contact($data);
    print_r($result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `preventDefault();` you can use `return false;` in the end of function `submit()` but I doubt this is the problem.

You should also use url encoding on `$('.feed-input').val()` use `encodeURIComponent` for this.

You should also check if you have errors in your console.

To determine if default action is prevented you can use `e.isDefaultPrevented()`. By default action in this case I mean submit action of the form with id feedInput.

You didn't name your param in data. Check [jquery ajax examples](http://api.jquery.com/ajax).

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting an error `e.preventDefault();` is not stopping the ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo site_url('dashboard/post_feed_item'); ?>",
    data: $("#form").serializeArray(),
    success: function(resp){
        $('#container').html(resp);
    },
    error: function(resp) { alert(JSON.stringify(resp)); }
});
```